# Piping input to pwdx

Tags: bash

I'm trying to understand why this one-liner to get the working directory of the most intensive process doesn't work

```
top -n 1 | grep -A 1 PID | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs pwdx
pwdx: invalid process id: 13620
```

When this does

```
echo 13620 | xargs pwdx
13620: /correct/working/directory
```

There isn't any trailing/leading whitespace in the output PID that gets  piped to xargs in the first example, but it still doesn't recognise it as a valid PID. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Very interesting, but I cannot reproduce

Comment: What does `top -n 1 | grep -A 1 PID | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f1` itself show?

Comment: This won't work in general. `top` lists space padded PID's. Which means it lists `sss1` (s is a blank space) instead of `0001` and when you pipe that to `cut -d' ' -f1` it will return an empty string. (I know you mentioned no leading whitespace, but just want to make this clear for someone that does not understand what you meant.)

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, it gives the string 13620 with no leading or trailing whitespace

Comment: @Quasímodo this is a good point, but I still don't understand why it's not working in this specific case

Comment: see answer below, you have bad caharacters in the TOP output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of Top contains special characters:

```
top -n 1 | grep -A1 PID | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs echo | cat -v
^[(B^[[m^[(B^[[m41039
```

Where 41039 is the pid

Use grep or similar to filter out the bad characters, id also use awk to get the first field

```
top -n 1 | grep -A1 PID | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}' | grep -o -E '[0-9]+' | xargs pwdx
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your cut command, use the -b(counting the byte of your output and adjusting the option) option and not the -f that is not reliable.

```
top -n 1 | grep -A 1 PID | tail -1  | cut -b11-12 | xargs pwdx
```